# Should I be concerned with the accumulation of road cinder in my garage?

Tags: cleaning, garage

Albuquerque, like many municipalities during snow storms has its roadways scraped and covered in a sand cinder mixture. This winter has gotten off to an early start and the road crews have been out in force making our roads safe. The trouble is the sand cinder mixture used to assist with traction on roadways is starting to accumulate in my garage.

Is there a potential for harm to my garage's concrete floor? Do I need to be diligent about sweeping it out of the garage or can I wait until things warm up a little? I know this stuff washes away in the street, but should I be doing something to dispose of it rather than just brushing it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think there is much to worry about.  Living in the snow belt in Ohio, our garage is almost completely black by the end of the winter.  We try to brush or even spray it our a few times if the weather permits.  But that is really to keep it from tracking into the house, not so much for the floor.

I would be more concerned with salt on your garage floor than the cinders.  The salt can certainly eat away and break down the concrete.

There are concrete sealers that you could apply in warmer weather than might help to protect it, but I have never heard of anyone doing that in a garage.